# Why did this query crash the server?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I ran this query in a warehouse management system earlier today and it caused our system to freeze up. I'm extremely new to SQL. Did I join the tables incorrectly? Do I need any more filtering? Any help is appreciated. Can provide a db dictionary if needed.

```
SELECT customer.name AS Clinic,  so.num AS SONum,  product.num AS
       ProductNum, trackinginfo.info AS Lot, soitem.qtyfulfilled AS Qty,
       soitem.unitprice AS UnitPrice 
FROM customer
INNER JOIN so ON customer.id=so.customerid
LEFT JOIN soitem ON so.id=soitem.soid
LEFT JOIN product ON soitem.productid=product.id
INNER JOIN part ON product.partid=part.id
LEFT JOIN parttotracking ON part.id=parttotracking.partid
LEFT JOIN parttracking ON parttotracking.parttrackingid=parttracking.id
LEFT JOIN trackinginfo ON parttracking.id=trackinginfo.parttrackingid
WHERE customer.name LIKE '%paragon%'
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`? It's more expensive, so you shouldn't use it unless really necessary.

Comment: Do you have indexes on all the columns used in the joins?

Comment: If there are lots of rows matching all these joins, it may just be generating a huge result, and also locking all those table rows, which blocks other applications querying the tables.

Comment: @Barmar, the only resource I have for the tables is located at this link: https://www.fishbowlinventory.com/files/databasedictionary/2017/index.html do you think if I changed the INNER JOIN to LEFT it will work better?

Comment: It will probably work better, but it might not solve the whole problem. But it might also give an incorrect answer -- do you need to include customers who have no `soitem`, `product`, or `trackinginfo`?

Comment: I looked at a few of the tables and they all had appropriate indexes, I assume the rest are OK as well. It may just be that this is producing a huge result and it's overloading the server.

Comment: @Barmar What I need is to query all soitem, product, and trackinginfo for a specific group of customers with "paragon" in their name. Every customer should have at the very least 1 of each of these columns. Any way you can think of to optimize it to not overload the server?

Comment: If they should all have matches in the tables, use `INNER JOIN`. You only use `LEFT JOIN` if you need to include rows that don't have matches.

Comment: Okay. And this will be less resource intensive?

Comment: Yes. Although if the query is so bad that it kills the server, it might not be enough of an improvement.

Comment: `soitem` and `product` will be treated as inner join, because they are both referenced (directly or not) by `inner join part`, so it doesn't matter much what you use there. If you indeed **need** to get `trackinginfo.info` then using `inner join` will be better as it will reduce result set.

Can we see query plan?